# Fragment has unsaved changes - how to prevent the fragment from closing when back is pressed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm using `NavController`:

```
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_user);
navController.navigate(R.id.nav_fragment_user_data);
```

In my `UserSettingsActivity`, there is an `onBackPressed` method and I want to do something like this (pseudo code):

```
[...]

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    
    Fragment f = navController.getCurrentFragment(); // dream... maybe in another universe...
    if(f instanceof UserDataFragment){
        UserDataFragment userDataFragment = (UserDataFragment)f;
        if(userDataFragment.hasUnsavedChanges()){
            return; // ignore or show warning
        }
    }

    finish();
}
```

since `onBackPressed` can only be overwritten in Activity, there must be a way to access the current fragment to check its status

Comment: There are hundreds of SO answers on how to get current fragment from NavController. Anyway, I would suggest to use OnBackPressedCallback directly in the fragment.

Comment: Did you read the [guide to customizing the back button](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#implement)? It actually has an example of intercepting back in a Fragment.